# Password based AES Encryption and Decryption - BadPaddingException

Tags: java, security, cryptography, java-security

everyone.

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a string with an AES symmetric key, generated with a password. My current code for generating this follows below:

```
public class AESUtils {

    public static SecretKey getKeyFromPassword(String password, String salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        return new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec)
                .getEncoded(), "AES");
    }

    public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }

    public static String encryptPasswordBased(String plainText, SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));
    }

    public static String decryptPasswordBased(String cipherText, SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText)));
    }

}
```

The code to generate the encrypted string:

```
AESUtils.encryptPasswordBased(string_content_plain, AESUtils.getKeyFromPassword("password", "salt"), AESUtils.generateIv());
```

The code to generate the decrypted string:

```
AESUtils.decryptPasswordBased(string_content_encrypted, AESUtils.getKeyFromPassword("password", "salt"), AESUtils.generateIv());
```

The `encryptPasswordBased` works fine, but when I use the `decryptPasswordBased`, it always raises javax.crypto.BadPaddingException with the message: `Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`

What can I do? The generated key is always the same. I have compared it with both byte arrays.

Thanks

Comment: You correctly create a random IV during encryption. You do the same for decryption, which is however wrong for decryption. Instead, the IV of the encryption must be used. Usually the (non-secret) IV and the ciphertext are concatenated after encryption and sent to the receiver, which separates both parts and then performs the decryption.

Answer (score 0):

As @Topaco said, the solution was to use the same IV when decrypting the content. The generation of a new one would make it impossible to decrypt.